# How can i make my integer to be exactly in the number of digits that i gave in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to accept only the number that is given in the number of digits that I chose. How can i do that in Oracle?

Comment: You need a check constraint

Comment: I am not writing the database with code but In Oracle. So how can i add the constraint? What to write into Add Constraint box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(
  supplier_id numeric(4),
  supplier_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT check_supplier_id
  ***CHECK (supplier_id BETWEEN 100 and 9999)***
);
```